# Hybrid A* algorithm Vs A* algorithm, what is the difference between both in Pseudocode

Tags: algorithm, a-star

I am doing an auto-moving car robot that will be using an algorithm. Base on my research I find that hybrid A* algorithm can do better work on finding a shorter path which will have a smooth turn for the car rather than the A* algorithm that will create a 90 degree turn on the spot. I cannot find any pseudocode for hybrid A* algorithm but there is A* algorithm pseudocode. So I was wondering is there any difference in the pseudocode?

Comment: Presumably "the hybrid A* algorithm" means "the algorithm that I have described somewhere and which is heavily inspired by A*". I don't think there is one algorithm universally referred to as "the hybrid A* algorithm". Which source mentioned this algorithm?

Comment: I saw this video where it shows the difference between hybrid A* and A* (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QAzyG2DB8Io).

Answer (score 1):

Hybrid A* is an extension of the classical A* algorithm designed to take into account the non-holonomic nature of a car-like vehicle. It was released in the form of an academic research paper in 2009 by Dmitri Dolgov et al. as part of the DARPA Urban Challenge.